# Running a user interactive cmd with crontab without user interaction

Tags: cron, aix

I have a command which takes 2 arguments.

When I run the command manually, I do this way:

```
cmd -i xyz.dat 
hit enter
enter password in the prompt
hit enter
confirm password
```

and the command runs successfully.

When I am doing this in the crontab to run it every 30 min like this:

```
30 *  *  *  * /$HOME/cmd -i xyz.dat mypwd   mypwd
```

The `cmd`-script needs user interaction (inputing password) when I run manually.
Can you please help how do I run a crontab job without user interaction?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That doesn't run every 30 minutes; it runs every hour at 30 minutes past the hour. Replace the `30` with `*/30` or `0,30`. It looks like your command prompts for a password. Feeding it a password from a cron job is going to be tricky. You could modify `cmd` to take the password as a command-line argument, but that's insecure, since you'll have to have the password *in clear text* in your crontab.

Comment: I have no idea what `cmd` does, except that it apparently reads a password interactively. I don't know whether it reads it from standard input, from `/dev/tty`, or by some other mechanism. I presume you still need to provide a password to `cmd` somehow, but there just isn't enough information to say anything more concrete.

Comment: The command I am trying to run is gsa_logger -i login.dat   When I press enter it prompts for a pwd and entering again prompts password confirmation.

Comment: I don't know what `gsa_logger` is. I think your real question more about running `gsa_logger` non-interactively than about crontab. I suggest updating the question. (Don't assume people will see information in the comments.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70184/discussion-between-smiley-and-keith-thompson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My two suggestions would be:

1. trying to echo the password to the script (manually) to see if the command will read the password from stdin. You could hide the password in a wrapper script (keeps it out of cron, anyway).
2. use expect to provide the input